# pandas slice a data frame based on the condition and timestamp sequence

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a Label column to a data frame when column A > 1 and delta timestamp is  more than 2 days

```
Time              A          Label
2019-02-1        0.1          
2019-02-2        1.1
2019-02-3        0.2
2019-02-4        0.3
2019-02-5        1.1          
2019-02-6        1.1          
2019-02-7        2.1          
2019-02-8        0.4
2019-02-9        0.5
2019-02-10       1.6          
2019-02-11       1.7          
2019-02-12       2.1          
2019-02-13       4.4          
2019-02-14       0.5
```

The result should be

```
Time              A           Label
2019-02-1        0.1          False
2019-02-2        1.1          False
2019-02-3        0.2          False
2019-02-4        0.3          False
2019-02-5        1.1          True
2019-02-6        1.1          True
2019-02-7        2.1          True
2019-02-8        0.4          False
2019-02-9        0.5          False
2019-02-10       1.6          True
2019-02-11       1.7          True
2019-02-12       2.1          True
2019-02-13       4.4          True
2019-02-14       0.5          False
```

and how can I get the time range based on the Label column

Comment: Can you please explain more about "delta timestamp is more than 2 days"?

Comment: if 3 days after each other (continuously) the A >1 then set Lable as True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cumsum` create the `groupby` key , then you can using `transform`

```
g = df.loc[df.A.ge(1),'Time'].groupby(df.A.le(1).cumsum())
df['Label']=(g.transform('last')-g.transform('first')).dt.days>1
df.Label=df.Label.fillna(False)
df
         Time    A  Label
0  2019-02-01  0.1  False
1  2019-02-02  1.1  False
2  2019-02-03  0.2  False
3  2019-02-04  0.3  False
4  2019-02-05  1.1   True
5  2019-02-06  1.1   True
6  2019-02-07  2.1   True
7  2019-02-08  0.4  False
8  2019-02-09  0.5  False
9  2019-02-10  1.6   True
10 2019-02-11  1.7   True
11 2019-02-12  2.1   True
12 2019-02-13  4.4   True
13 2019-02-14  0.5  False
```